# Android - According to what Firebase refreshing token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Maybe it is not important but I dont understood that when `onTokenRefresh()` function running.. Thank you

Edit : I m using FCM Notification on my Android project. My app send message to specific users with "registration token id"(I'm storing this). I worried about that when token id will change or is it literal values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register):

> Because the token could be rotated after initial startup, you are strongly recommended to retrieve the latest updated registration token.
>
> The registration token may change when:
>
> - The app deletes Instance ID
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.